# How to align partitions of two dask dataframes

Tags: python, dask

I have two dask dataframes which are first read in pandas, indexed on their respective "zo_id" columns, and then converted to dask dataframes with 4 partitions:

```
drivetimes = pd.read_sql('QUERY1',engine)
drivetimes.set_index('zo_id', inplace=True)
drivetimes = dd.from_pandas(drivetimes, npartitions=4)
drivetimes.npartitions
drivetimes.divisions
```

(623725, 627468, 631429, 636360, 645492)

```
calc_zones = pd.read_sql('QUERY2',engine)
calc_zones.rename(columns={"re_id": "z_re_id"}, inplace=True)
calc_zones.set_index('zo_id', inplace=True)
calc_zones = dd.from_pandas(calc_zones, npartitions=4)
calc_zones.npartitions
calc_zones.divisions
```

(623725, 629167, 634609, 640051, 645492)

As you can see these divisions are not aligned, and when I merge both dataframes using their respective indexes:

```
j1 = dd.merge(drivetimes, calc_zones, on='zo_id', left_index = True, right_index = True, how='inner')
j1.shape[0].compute()
```

I can see in the dashboard that the graph starts with repartitioning tasks. How can I "pre-align" the partitions of these two dataframes so that I don't have to repeat re-shuffling data every time I do a computation ?

Answer (score 0):

The `dd.from_pandas` function accepts a `divisions=` keyword